# Why should we use double quotes inside html input tag attribute values?

Tags: html, attributes, double-quotes

Please explain what is the difference between these two lines:

```
 <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="zip" value="95131" /> 

 <input type=text size=10 maxlength=10 name=zip value=95131 />
```

Both render.

**What are the benefits/drawbacks of using double quotes (") ?**

Comment: Please, this is not a duplicate question. The link to the other item explains why it is a good practice to use quotes. This one asks why double quotes instead of single quotes. I don't know the difference, but Eclipse version 2019 warns you when using single quotes for HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp

Excerpt from link:

> **We Suggest: Always Quote Attribute Values**
>
> The HTML5 standard does not require quotes around attribute values.
>
> W3C **recommends** quotes in HTML4, and **demands** quotes for stricter document types like XHTML.
>
> Sometimes it is **necessary** to use quotes.

Comment: Sorry, but this link explains why use quotes, it does NOT disclose why to use double quotes instead of single quotes.